Popstate not firing before react UseEffect cleanup
I have a more complex setup, but have boiled my hook down to the most minimum example:
import { useEffect } from "react";

const useUnsavedChangesAlert = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (event) => {
      console.log("IN HANDLE ROUTE CHANGE!!");
    };

    console.log("ADD POPSTATE EVENT LISTENER!!");
    window.addEventListener("popstate", handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      console.log("REMOVE POPSTATE EVENT LISTENER!!");
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, []);
};

export default useUnsavedChangesAlert;

The purpose of this is the classic 'Are you sure?' popup when a user attempts to navigate away from a page, where they might lose some changes. While I have removed that functionality just for proof of concept, I would tend to expect that when I click the back button, the popstate event listener would fire the handleRouteChange function and then the page would route away and the useEffect return would unregister the event listener.
However, the log statement in the handleRouteChange function is not printing at all. Is it possible that the cleanup function is running first, therefore unregistering the event listener, before the event listener has a chance to fire? I was under the impression that the event listener fired first. I think the concern is that the back arrow in the browser would unmount the component, thereby running the useEffect cleanup function and removing the event handler. Is that happening before or after the event has a chance to fire?
Is this what is happening, or is there a different problem here? What might be a good way to fix this so that I can have the event listener fire prior to the cleanup function running?

To address some of the comments - laktherock provided a codesandbox where this issue does not exist. I am using a Next JS 14 app, so to try to copy his sandbox I built a very simple create-react-app with just a couple bare-bones components to demonstrate this bug, and it DOES still exist. I don't know why it worked in the code sandbox - possibly because the sandbox has some sort of isolated browser simulation and the event listeners work differently there, or because he was using some pretty outdated dependencies. But here is the code for my minimum reproduced example:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (event) => {
      console.log("IN HANDLE ROUTE CHANGE!!");
      alert("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
    };

    console.log("ADD POPSTATE EVENT LISTENER!!");
    window.addEventListener("popstate", handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      console.log("REMOVE POPSTATE EVENT LISTENER!!");
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, []);
  return <h1>Home</h1>;
}

I can also confirm that the issue is NOT what SS87 said about interacting with the page - this is because if I comment out the removeEventListener line, the handleRouteChange function runs perfectly as expected.
This leads me to my most recent discovery - the cleanup function from the useEffect hook seems to be removing the popstate event listener before the event listener has a chance to fire. This is odd, because I have found lots of things online talking about how important it is to cleanup / remove any event listeners that were specifically added to a particular component when that component unmounts. However, in this case, that is sort of a circular dilemma because the popstate event listener is expected to fire when the user navigates away; however, the act of navigating away unmounts the component and therefore removes the event listener before it has a chance to fire. This is odd to me because I would expect that this would be a pretty common use case - that is, to alert the user before navigating away incase they have unsaved changes. I would think there would be a popular / common way to fix this, but have come up short finding a solution. Any further ideas sure would be helpful!!

I tried the script provided above, and it printed the expected output and behaved as anticipated. It seems there may be an issue with other sections of the code.
Please check the code sandbox url for reference: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-router-dom-example-forked-48q9cw?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Your useEffect should operate correctly in itself. Without any other code to go on, perhaps the issue is with the event itself in relation to the browser;
According to the documentation, MDN: Popstate "It's important to first understand that — to combat unwanted pop-ups — browsers may not fire the popstate event at all unless the page has been interacted with."

After further investigation, and really dumbing down my app (I was using a next js 14 app, but I ended up reproducing this bug in a very minimum create-react-app), I have discovered that the use effect IS in fact running the cleanup function prior to the popstate event function firing. This can be see by simply commenting out the removeEventListener and observing that the 'remove' log statement prints prior to the log statement in the event listener function. Basically, the use effect is intending to operation when navigate away, but the same action is removing the eventListener on cleanup..??

I am still looking for a solution to this. It is very puzzling - I would think this would be a pretty common use case. There is lots of stuff on the Internet about how to properly cleanup an event listener - but in this case, it is ironic because the cleanup is preventing the expected functionality. For example, I expect the popstate event handler to run when the user navigates away, but the cleanup function remove the event handler when the component is unmounted (aka when the user navigates away). Sort of a circular dilemma.

Im running in to the same issues as you are Luke, the way im going around it right now is to remove the listner in my callback instead, this works for my scenario but might not really solve the issue for you.. If you find a way to solve this please let me know :)
useEffect(() => {
    const handlePopState = () => {
        window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        navigate('/somewhere');
    };
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
}, []);

